# How to get params in nested route in react router v6? It's not working on my project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My code is not working. Here is my `App.js` file:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} >
          <Route path="teachers" element={<Teachers />} >
            <Route exact path="single/:id" element={<SingleTeacher />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my code where I am routing the `teachers/single/{id}` route:

```
export default function TeacherCard({ name, spacial_at, teacher_pic_url, _id }) {
  return (
    <div className="bg-white shadow-lg py-4 px-3 rounded-lg flex md:flex-row flex-col justify-between items-center">
      <div className='relative'>
        <img className='h-16 w-16 object-cover rounded-full' src={teacher_pic_url} alt={name} loading={'lazy'} />
        <span className='absolute bottom-1 right-1 rounded-full px-1 py-1 bg-green-500 border border-white'></span>
      </div>
      <div className='flex md:pl-3 flex-col w-2/3 text-center md:text-left'>
        <span className=' font-semibold text-md'>{name}</span>
        <span className='text-gray-400 text-xs'>{spacial_at}</span>
        <Link to={`single/${_id}`} className='text-grad-to text-xs mt-2 md:text-left'>View profile</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This code takes me to the route successfully but I can't get the `id` params in `<SingleTeacher />` route. Here is my `SingleTeacher.js` file:

```
export default function SingleTeacher() {
    console.log(useParams());
  return (
    <div>SingleTeacher</div>
  )
}
```

But It can't be logging any information to the console.

Comment: Where is `TeacherCard` component rendered? Can you also share all relevant code you are working with? What is `Teachers` rendering? See [mcve].

Comment: I believe you need to render `<Outlet />` in `Teachers`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given:

```
<Route path="teachers" element={<Teachers />} >
  <Route exact path="single/:id" element={<SingleTeacher />} />
</Route>
```

Then it seems this `Teachers` component as a layout route is missing rendering an `Outlet` component for the nested route rendering `SingleTeacher`.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Teachers = () => {
  ....

  return (
    <>
      ....

      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render element here

      ....
    </>
  );
};
```

See:

- [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes)
- [Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet)